# Bitwise operator in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

Can we do `bitwise and` in a firebird procedure without using a UDF? is there
one of the built in function or is there a way to get the same results
with standard built in commands?

I tried http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-bin_and.html (BIN_AND) also but i need some implementation without UDF.

Ex: `(3 & 3) returns 3` in SQL but not in firebird(firebird 2.1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebird doesn't have bitwise operators, the `BIN_AND()` function is the way to go. Since Firebird 2.1 those `BIN_*` functions are **internal functions**, ie they are always available without need to any external DLL or registering them as UDF.